# How to scale image in css so that it fits entirely within browser window?

Tags: html, css

I am working on a web site where the user views a gallery and has the option to click on a thumbnails of pictures. Upon clicking, the image will open up in full size.
The problem I am having is that certain images, in either landscape or portrait orientation, will not scale properly. For example, the full size image will be missing the bottom half. How can I fit the entire image in the browser window? Or at least make it so that the user can use the scrollbars to view the whole image if it stretches beyond the boundaries?

Here is a snippet of my CSS:

```
.img-cont{
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: top center;
background-size: cover;
}

.box-expanded .img-cont{ 
box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1); 
float: left; 
width: 100%;
height: 100% 
margin-right: 20px; 
box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1); 

}
```

Comment: Are you using images as `background` OR `<img>` ?

Comment: Can you post a link to the website? And by scale you meant to say resize the image?

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay These images are being placed as `background-image`.
@user3275665 The work has not been uploaded to a web site yet as I am editing all the code off-line first...and yes, I mean to resize the image.

Comment: Any thoughts on this one?